# Neo4j java traversal api object mapping

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to map the result of TraversalDescription.traverse() to a list of custom Node and Relationship Object.

If I use Cypher with sdn, I can do the following:

```
@Query("WITH {0} AS ns, {1} AS ne " +
    "MATCH p=(n1{name:ns})-[*]-(n), (n2{name:ne}) " +
    "WHERE n=n2 " +
    "AND all(a IN nodes(p) WHERE single(x IN nodes(p) WHERE x=a)) " +
    "RETURN nodes(p) as persons, rels(p) as connections " +
    "ORDER BY size(nodes(p))")
List<GraphPath> getAllPaths(String startNode, String endNode);
```

then map to the GraphPath object that contains custom node and relationship Object:

GraphPath.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@QueryResult
public class GraphPath {    
    private List<Person> persons;
    private List<Connection> connections;    
}
```

Person.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@NodeEntity(label = "Person")
public class Person extends Entity{

    @Property(name = "name")
    private String fullName;

    @Property(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @Relationship(type = "CONNECTS", direction = Relationship.UNDIRECTED)
    private Set<Connection> personConnections = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Connection.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@RelationshipEntity(type = "CONNECTS")
public class Connection extends Entity{

    @Property(name="connection_id")
    private String connectId;

    @Property(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @StartNode
    private Person personSource;

    @EndNode
    private Person personTarget;
}
```

and Entity.java is just POJO with field id and overrided equals() and hashCode()

This is working fine in simple graph, but when the graph gets more complicated, the time to get the result will increase much more. I am aiming to find all possible paths between start and end node, and there is no repeated node or relationship in each path. I am hoping to use traversal API to eliminate some of the unwanted path (path that contains repeated node or relationship) on the run in order to reduce process time.

Here is the code I use, and graphDb is just GraphDatabaseService:

```
final Node startNode = graphDb.findNode(Labels.Person, "name", startNodeName);
final Node endNode = graphDb.findNode(Labels.Person, "name", endNodeName);
TraversalDescription td = graphDb.traversalDescription()
        .depthFirst()
        .evaluator(Evaluators.excludeStartPosition())
        .evaluator(Evaluators.includeWhereEndNodeIs(endNode))
        .relationships(Types.CONNECTS)
                .uniqueness(Uniqueness.NODE_PATH)
                .uniqueness(Uniqueness.RELATIONSHIP_PATH);
Traverser t = td.traverse(startNode)
```

Now the question is, **how can I map the result to the custom object I mentioned above?** Doing it manually will get to a point where I have to deal with recursive object mapping (the Set of Connection in Person, and the target and source Person in Connection).

Comment: Side note: you can only set one `uniqueness`, last one wins. `Uniqueness.NODE_PATH` is enough, because a `Path` always ends with a `Node` and if it starts traversing a relationship a second time (in the other direction), it will stop when reaching the node.

Comment: @Frank Pavageau Thanks for the note. Any thought on the mapping part?

Comment: I haven't used SDN 4 yet, so I can't really comment on the mapping part. I think I'd just do it by hand, as the only thing left to fetch from the database is the properties, when using SDN might fetch relationship data again (maybe not when using a depth of 0, from what I've skimmed) and you seem to be looking for the most efficient algorithm. I'm also not sure if you expect the same `Person` instance in all `GraphPath` instances referencing the same `Node`, or just equal ones.

Comment: Thanks. I am currently doing it manually to temporally process to my next step, however, the downside is that I have to give up mapping relationship on each node otherwise it will run into recursive mapping issue. 
Person doesn't need to be same reference across GraphPath.

Comment: I don't see how you can have recursive mapping issues if you iterate on the `Path`: map a `Person`, keep it aside, map a `Relationship`, use the `Person` you just mapped in the `Relationship` and add the `Relationship` to the `Person`, keep the `Relationship` aside, map a `Person`, use the `Relationship`, etc. There's no recursivity in there.

Comment: You are right. I guess I was trying to create new `Person` or `Relationship` every time I did the mapping. So does that mean I have to map the entire connected graph? Let's say I have **(a)-[A]->(b)-[B]->(c)**, and try to find path **(b)** to **(c)**. Normally, I should have **(b)**, **(c)**, and **[B]**. However, in order to map **(b)**, I will have to map **[A]** since it is one of the **(b)**'s `Relationship`, and same for **(a)** since that is **[A]**'s target `Person`, and so on.

Comment: Your DTO classes use getters and setters, not final fields, so you can create a partial `Person` or `Relationship` and complete it afterwards. You don't need `[A]` while you're mapping `(b)`, you can always add it afterwards.

Comment: Re-reading your comment, I don't understand why you'd need to map `a` and `A` if you're looking for the path from `b` to `c`: shouldn't the `GraphPath` only contain the nodes and relationships from the path found (that's what I think the Cypher query does)? It looks like you're trying to get the path *and all its connected sub-graph*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments, I think I would just do the mapping manually, since the `Path` returned by the `Traverser` already contain the nodes and relationships and only the properties now need to be read.

By iterating on the `Path`, the `GraphPath` and its `Person`s and `Connection`s can be constructed and completed sequentially. This code can obviously be refactored by extracting methods.

```
for (Path path : t) {
    GraphPath gp = new GraphPath();
    Person person = null;
    Connection connection = null;

    for (PropertyContainer pc : path) {
        if (pc instanceof Node) {
            Node node = (Node) pc;

            person = new Person();
            person.setId(node.getId());
            person.setFullName(node.getProperty("name", null));
            person.setStatus(node.getProperty("status", null));
            gp.getPersons().add(person);

            // No connection exists for the first node in the path
            if (connection != null) {
                // Find out which end has already been connected
                if (connection.getPersonSource() == null) {
                    connection.setPersonSource(person);
                } else {
                    connection.setPersonTarget(person);
                }
                person.getPersonConnections().add(connection);
            }
        } else {
            Relationship rel = (Relationship) pc;

            connection = new Connection();
            connection.setId(rel.getId());
            connection.setConnectId(rel.getProperty("connection_id", null));
            connection.setStatus(rel.getProperty("status", null));
            gp.getConnections().add(connection);

            // Find out which end has already been mapped
            if (rel.getStartNode().getId() == person.getId().longValue()) {
                connection.setPersonSource(person);
            } else {
                connection.setPersonTarget(person);
            }
            person.getPersonConnections().add(connection);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want a single `Person` (resp. `Connection`) instance for a given node, you can change the `Person` (resp. `Connection`) creation to look up a `Map` first, where you'll index the entities by id; you'll also have to change the wiring of the `Person` and `Connection` together to only set unset ends on the `Connection`, and not rely on the fact that one end or another is still null.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! This should be the solution when there is no automatic way to map